# How to give custom extension for sql-server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I wanted to give a Custom extension to my database file , let say ".abc" instead of .mdf , so that user thinks it is a proprietary stuff . 
When doing it by simply changing extension , and running unit test for generating database , it is throwing exception.

What is the correct way to do this. Any tutorial link  will be helpful too.

Just giving additional details , I am using WPF and MVVM approach for my application.

Comment: Have you tried running unit test for a database file without extension? Just Remove .mdf from database so it will be converted into a Unknown File, if unit test works fine, then you can easily add an extension to the unknown file, But Note that this extension should be a part of file name and not an exact sham extension. Hope I'm Clear Enough.

Comment: Removing .mdf from database is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I will not suggest you to do that. Changing the extension from .mdf to some other name will not be a good idea.

On a workaround you can instead zip your .mdf to folder and then you can rename it
 as per your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

So , giving custom extension is not a problem . I go through Microsoft documentation where they have mentioned clearly that .mdf for primary database and .ldf for log file is standard convention not a requirement.
Why was I not able to generate the custom extension database earlier because I was trying to do some logic like "ChangeExtensionName" or Move the database which is not at all required.